# sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcast: No existe el fichero o el directorio

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I have a Debian 9 Stretch and I'm configuring as webserver. For this I'm applying rules in iptables and another parameters in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

I would like to apply this rule in FW:(it's inside the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`)

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcast = 1
```

And the system show this error:

> sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcast: file not exist

It's missing any module or something, I don't know... Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're missing the trailing "s" in the name of the option: it's actually named "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcast**s**".

A couple more hints for the future:

1. Please don't cheat on us: the kernel could not say "file not exist" because

   - It's not a proper English.
   - A canonical translation for the `ENOENT` error (something was not
     found on a filesystem) is "No such file or directory".

     I would speculate you have a non-English locale enabled,
     and so the error was not in English, so you "translated" it.

     This is a wrong thing to do: the error message cannot be properly googled.

     When you need to get a "canonical" error message (to google for it
     or to ask for help, like in this case), re-try your action with the English
     (or neutral) locale—an example

     ```
     ~$ ls /foo
     ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/foo': Нет такого файла или каталога
     ```

     okay, not too useful to see this in Russian; so let's ask for English:

     ```
     ~$ LANGUAGE=en ls /foo
     ls: cannot access '/foo': No such file or directory
     ```
2. Once you have sorted the canonical error message thing, just google it.
   You'll see it will even try to correct you ([watch for youself](https://www.google.ru/search?q="%2Fproc%2Fsys%2Fnet%2Fipv4%2Ficmp_echo_ignore_broadcast")).
3. Why not just look under the offending directory hierarchy?
   A quick

   ```
   $ ls -1 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/
   ```

   would solve your mystery.